# Substitute method arguments in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arguments, substitution

how to bind a set of arguments to a variable and then use the variable as argument for a method, e.g.

```
my_method(arg_a, arg_b, arg_c, arg_d, arg_e)
```

should be expressed like something like that

```
my_args = [arg_a, arg_b, arg_c, arg_d, arg_e]
my_method(my_args)
```

But that doesn't work 'cause my_method expects 5 args but only get the array as one arg. I have few methods with the same arguments set so how to get this working to get DRYer code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the splat operator. Try this:

```
my_args = [arg_a, arg_b, arg_c, arg_d, arg_e]
my_method(*my_args)
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible candidate for variable length arguments/splat? http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/ruby_tutorial/Ruby_More_About_Methods_Variable-Length_Argument_Lists.html